# Face bounding box for face landmark detection

Tags: computer-vision, bounding-box

In face landmarks detection, we first find the face bounding box from the whole image, and then second we find the landmarks from this bounding box.

My question is, during training, should I use the ground truth face box, or the detected face box (just like how we find the box during testing)?

Thanks in advance!

Best,
Ruixin